# Wondering why "return () -> queryParam" can match type Provider in function of?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming

Wondering why `return () -> queryParam` can match type `Provider` in function of?
what format would you request?

```
public static Provider of(final QueryParam queryParam) {
    return () -> queryParam;
}

public interface Provider {
    QueryParam getQueryParam();
}
```

Comment: Because `Provider` has only one method and it can be written as a lambda instead of creating an extra class that implements the interface?

Answer (score 0):

Provider is a functional interface which takes no parameters and returns QueryParam, it is exactly what lambda '()->queryParam' defines